# Exception java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpenOrZipException with WAS 7

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jax-ws, websphere-7

When I am deploying an application on `WebSphere Application Server 7.0` , I am getting below exception and its taking too much time to deploy.
After few deployments the server start generating heap dumps and running out of memory.
In our application we are using `JAX-WS` for generating Web Service Clients.
We are also using `JSF 1.2` for view.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
000000ff annotations   E ClassScanner scanInputStream Exception occurred while scanning input stream:{0}
                                 java.util.zip.ZipException: ZipFile closed
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpenOrZipException(ZipFile.java:424)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1100(ZipFile.java:40)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:456)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.fill(ZipFile.java:241)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:152)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:229)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:269)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:328)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:127)
    at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:180)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:232)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:152)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:157)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:127)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:231)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl$1.applyTo(AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.java:259)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.amm.scan.context.ArchiveInputStreamData.iterate(ArchiveInputStreamData.java:241)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.scan(AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.java:257)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.scan(AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.java:218)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.commonarchive.AnnotationsProcessorImpl.merge(AnnotationsProcessorImpl.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.processAnnotations(WARFileImpl.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(WARFileImpl.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(WARFileImpl.java:173)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.WARFileImpl.getExtensions(WARFileImpl.java:440)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.WARFileImpl.getContextRoot(WARFileImpl.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.loadDeploymentDescriptor(Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.importMetaData(Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EARFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(EARFileImpl.java:377)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.EARFileImpl.initializeModuleExtensions(EARFileImpl.java:641)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.EARFileImpl.initializeAfterOpen(EARFileImpl.java:720)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openSpecificArchive(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:1517)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openEARFile(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:1205)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openEARFile(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:552)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.getArchive(AppInstallHelper.java:271)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.getEarFile(AppInstallHelper.java:157)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.admin.utils.CommonUtils.getMergeEar(CommonUtils.java:450)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.admin.deploy.ServiceIndexServerTask.performTask(ServiceIndexServerTask.java:126)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run(SchedulerImpl.java:284)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:735)

[9/13/12 12:00:44:138 IST] 000000ff annotations   E ArchiveInputStreamData iterate unable to open file iterator
                                 java.util.zip.ZipException: ZipFile closed
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpenOrZipException(ZipFile.java:424)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1100(ZipFile.java:40)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:456)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.fill(ZipFile.java:241)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:152)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:229)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:269)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:328)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:127)
    at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:180)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:232)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:152)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:157)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.closeEntry(ZipInputStream.java:103)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.NestedArchiveIteratorDirect.getInputStream(NestedArchiveIteratorDirect.java:117)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.amm.scan.context.ArchiveInputStreamData.iterate(ArchiveInputStreamData.java:238)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.scan(AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.java:257)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.scan(AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.java:218)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.commonarchive.AnnotationsProcessorImpl.merge(AnnotationsProcessorImpl.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.processAnnotations(WARFileImpl.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(WARFileImpl.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(WARFileImpl.java:173)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.WARFileImpl.getExtensions(WARFileImpl.java:440)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.WARFileImpl.getContextRoot(WARFileImpl.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.loadDeploymentDescriptor(Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.importMetaData(Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EARFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(EARFileImpl.java:377)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.EARFileImpl.initializeModuleExtensions(EARFileImpl.java:641)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.EARFileImpl.initializeAfterOpen(EARFileImpl.java:720)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openSpecificArchive(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:1517)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openEARFile(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:1205)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openEARFile(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:552)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.getArchive(AppInstallHelper.java:271)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.getEarFile(AppInstallHelper.java:157)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.admin.utils.CommonUtils.getMergeEar(CommonUtils.java:450)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.admin.deploy.ServiceIndexServerTask.performTask(ServiceIndexServerTask.java:126)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run(SchedulerImpl.java:284)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:735)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeeh,

Finally got the solution after a long  R&D :)

Below link contain useful information.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK85322

What we did just change the module level of application to 2.4 and placed wsdl folder under WebContent.
The main issue was due to annotation processing of the application at the time of deployment.
The deployment process for the module metadata requires a new step to scan the Java annotations data
from classes that are packaged in the module. 
As we are using JAX-WS as a client of WebServices it includes annotation processing. The processing of annotation of JAX-WS requires reading  of wsdl files to generate update clients for each deployments. In this process of reading wsdl it was facing problem as its located in WEB-INF folder initially. I just change the location of wsdl and its working fine now.

Comment: Hi, thanks for giving the resolution here itself. I was also facing the same problem and changing the application module worked for me, i did not changed the location of the wsdl folder though. But if i change the module to 2.4, then the web services.xml file is not getting generated. Is there some other way to fix this issue? In your case, dont you need the webservices.xml file to be generated? Please help

Comment: web.xml version 2.4 and lower don't support annotation scanning, so by lowering the module version, you avoid the error.  This looks like a product bug, so I would recommend opening a PMR with IBM.

Comment: adding the UseWSFEP61ScanPolicy: true in MANIFEST.MF is resolving the issue along with lowering the module version to 2.4. and yes, adding this entry in the manifest file will let us use the annotation as well. I verified that adding this entry in manifest will let us use the annotation.